# Convert DateTime String to Date-only when listing in comboBox

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datagridview, combobox

I have a `dataGridView_flaggedComments` where there's a column called `Comments_Date` (which is in a format of `31/12/2014 01:10:11 PM`), I am adding the date portion to `comboBox_stockDates` and if there are a few same dates e.g. `31/12/2014`, I would only want it to appear once in `comboBox_stockDates`, not repeated.

Here's my code, and it will list all the date&time in each row, but not grabbing the date-only portion. Could anyone point out which part of my code should I correct? Or it would be great if there's guidance to it. I apologise if I overlooked any similar questions. Thank you very much!

```
private void PopulateStockDatesIndex()
{
    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Clear();
    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add("Choose to Filter");
    comboBox_stockDates.FormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    DataView dataview_filterDate = (DataView)(dataGridView_flaggedComments.DataSource);
    foreach (DataRowView rowView in dataview_filterDate)
    {
        DataRow row = rowView.Row;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows[i].Cells["Comments_Date"].Value.ToString() != "")
            {
                if (!comboBox_stockDates.Items.Contains(row[1].ToString()))
                {
                    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add(row[1].ToString());
                }
                comboBox_stockDates.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2nd version**:

```
private void PopulateStockDatesIndex()
{
    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Clear();
    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add("Choose to Filter");
    comboBox_stockDates.FormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy";

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows[i].Cells["Comments_Date"].Value.ToString() != "")
            {
                string date = row.Field<DateTime>(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                if (!comboBox_stockDates.Items.Contains(date))
                {
                    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add(date);

                }
                comboBox_stockDates.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DateTime.ToString` returns a string representation of the `DateTime` which includes the time portion. You can use `dt.ToString("d")`, `dt.ToShortDateString` or `dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` if you only want the date part.

```
string date = row.Field<DateTime>(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
if (!comboBox_stockDates.Items.Contains(date))
{
    comboBox_stockDates.Items.Add(date);
}
```

You could also use `LINQ` which also sorts the dates if desired:

```
string[] distinctDates = dataview_filterDate.Table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<DateTime>(1).Date) // Date is used to get Distinct dates by day
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(dt => dt)
    .Select(dt => dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
    .ToArray();
comboBox_stockDates.Items.AddRange(distinctDates);
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you very much for pointing this out. I learned something new! :)) It works. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Shyuan: note that i've edited my answer to show another approach. You need to add `using System.Linq`(if you're not familiar with LINQ).

Comment: I see. Would you recommend doing a LINQ rather than the `if` statement? I was told about LINQ many times, seems like LINQ has its advantages, but I am just not familiar with it because I'm quite a newbie to programming.

Comment: @Shyuan: **I** would use LINQ; but use whatever you find better. In my opinion it's easier to read and to maintain. In this case it could be even more efficient(due to `Distinct` which uses a set). But that's the last important thing. LINQ also uses loops, but you don't see them.

Comment: Got it and thank you Tim :) I've marked yours as answer :) Have a good day ahead!

Comment: @Shyuan: just another hint, i have edited it again  since you ahve to use `DateTime.Date` to make `Distinct` working correctly in the LINQ approach

Comment: Hi Tim, once again thank you! :) I see the changes. ;)

Comment: Hi Tim, I wonder if you could help me out for the edited question (I've put it as "2nd version"). The `row` in `string date = row.Field<DateTime>(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");` wouldn't work if I apply at `DataGridViewRow` foreach loop. Do you mind looking at that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
select only the Date element from your DateTime list into a new list, and make a Dates property.

```
public List<DateTime> Dates => dataGridView_flaggedComments.Rows.Select(el => el.Field<DateTime>(1).Date).Distinct().ToList();
```

in the .xaml file Bind your ComboBox to the Dates property.

```
 <ComboBox Name="DateSelection" ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}"/>
```